# How to make backup of VMWare ESXi host from Centos 7 using the ISCSI target?

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, iscsi

I have the VMware ESXi 6.7 free version as the iSCSI initiator and the iSCSI target with CentOS 7 64bit. All of VMs installed in the iSCSI datastore. Is there any way to sync or copy the file from the iSCSI target directly? I'm afraid about data when something will happen with CentOS.

Edit for clarity:

VMware ESXi 6.7 free version
ESXi datastore is an iSCSI initiator

Would like to copy the virtual disk files in order to make backups.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a backup of your datastore in ESXi?  What device hosts the iSCSI target?  I would start by looking for software designed for the host to do block level backups of the iSCSI targets.

Comment: @Xalorous Yes, I am looking for the solution to backup VMs without turning it off. So I am thinking about if I can copy or sync vmdk file form iSCSI target server. I can easily just import the vhdk file to ESXi once the iscsi target server crash.

Comment: What device hosts the iSCSI target?

Comment: @Xalorous I have a Dell R820 to install CentOS 7 and set up iSCSI target to share the storage to Vmware ESX 6.7. For the Vmware, all of the VMs were installed in the iSCSI datastore.

Comment: [related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/311459/how-to-backup-virtual-machines-on-a-standalone-esxi-host).  The solution only works if the VM is powered off and has no active snapshots.

[Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=backup+vm+esxi&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl) shows multiple utilities, some free, which may do what you wish.